# Differentiable complex function at $z_0$=0

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Is the function f defined by

$f(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{z Re(z)} { \vert z\vert},  & \text{if $z$ $\neq$ 0} \\
 0, & \text{if $z$=0}
\end{cases}$

differentiable at $0$ ?

So If I write f as f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) and If I verify that u and v have continuous partial derivatives, and also if u and v satisfies the cauchy-riemann equations at $z_0$=0, then I assure that f is differentiable at $z_o$=0.

Is there an easiest way to verify that f is differentiable at $0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, evaluate:

$$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h=\frac{h\,\text{Re}\,h}{|h|\,h}=\frac{\text{Re}\,h}{|h|}$$

If we put $\;h=a+ib\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;$ , and if we choose $\;a=mb\;,\;\;m\;$ a parameter, then

$$\frac{\text{Re}\,h}{|h|}=\left|\frac{mb}{\sqrt{m^2b^2+b^2}}\right|=\frac{|mb|}{\sqrt{b^2}\,\sqrt{1+m^2}}\xrightarrow[b\to0]{}\frac m{\sqrt{m^2+1}}$$

and we see the limit depends on $\;m\;$ and it thus doesn't exist.

Comment: as the limit depends on m then it doesn't exist. You say that because the limit can be different for different values of m? For example  if m=0, then the limit is zero. And if m=1, then the limit is 1/sqrt(2) ?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Exactly that.

Comment: why did you use absolute value for the fraction in the second equality?

Comment: Because I wanted to included both cases of real $\;a,\,b\;$  in one single instance. It is really not that important in this case.

Comment: but the result still holds if you weren't use absolute value?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Yes, and even worse: $$\frac{mb}{\sqrt{b^2}\sqrt{1+m^2}}\xrightarrow[b\to0]{}\pm\frac m{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$ depending on the sign of $\;b\;$ ...which can even *not* be well defined as $\;b\to0\;$ .

Comment: Oh I see, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is defined in an ordinary way. At $0$ this leads to $$\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\frac{\text{Re}\,z}{|z|}.$$ So, passing to $z=x+iy$ we get $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$ Check whether or not it exists.

Comment: I think it doesn't exist because $ \sqrt {x^2 +y^2 }$ goes to $0$. Am I right?

Comment: This argument is not correct. Observe Don Antonio's answer. My one is as follows: for $y=0$ our fraction does not have one-sided limits at $x\to 0^{\pm}$. That is why our limit does not exist.